# The cost/benefit of Changed?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-kingsport-horror

In Kingsport, you can become `Changed` which confers rather [a lot of nice abilities](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Changed). However, I am not sure that the balance is right.  It takes 10 toughness or 2 gates or 1 gate & 5 toughness to get. In addition, it takes around 7/8 turns to get and be ready to use it.  This mean that the benefits are likely to be relevant for the last half-dozen or so turns before the game ends -- the end game basically.  This makes the Seal (part of changed) you get kinda useless since maybe one or two gates might open on its location and chances are small that they will be gate bursts.

Compare this with either the `White Ship` ([link](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Captain_of_the_White_Ship)) or `Deputy of Arkham` ([link](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Deputy_of_Arkham)) which in my not so humble opinion are of equal power to `Changed` and to each other and are well within reach in early to mid game.

So:

1. Is my analysis of `Changed` correct?
2. If it is broken, how can we fix it?

**PS**: *I get that the last question might pool arguments and discussions. So, please adhere to the [Good Subjective/Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) rules. Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My group decided on this house rule:  `Changed` costs 10 toughness or 2 gates or 1 gate & 5 toughness to get.  However, the path to get it costs *two move points* instead of one and you *are not forced to stop* on the way. This make getting there much easier while keeping the cost high.  It is not a perfect solution but it makes `Changed` worthwhile.